# Installing PWA + php app - "OAuth 1.0 officially deprecated, migrate to OAuth 2.0" notice

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, picasa

Trying to set up / install the last stand alone version of PWA + PHP and am having Google auth problems.

The error says:

> Important: OAuth 1.0 has been officially deprecated as of April 20,
>   2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible. For details
>   about how to do this, see Migrating from OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0. To
>   get help on Stack Overflow, tag your questions with 'google-oauth'.

The plugin admin says:

> "this is not really an error, but more of a warning for the future. It
>   should still work assuming you added your WP domain at the link below.
>   Have you done that already? 
>   https://accounts.google.com/ManageDomains"

When I go to the link is when I get the above error.

I am not a programmer or app/plugin developer.  I'm just trying to install the Picasa web album plugin on a website.

Comment: If the plugin is warning you about the Oauth shutdown in 4 days I think you should contact the developer of the plug in for an upgrade.  Its going to stop working.

Comment: @dalmTo - 4 days?.  The only date I see in the error states April 12, 2012.  Twenty Twelve.  And the plugin developer/admin did reply... which I put in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 1.0 for Google Accounts will be [shut down](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/03/reminder-to-migrate-to-oauth-20-or.html) on April 20, 2015. Please let the developer know if you are in contact with them. They should [migrate to OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth_ref?utm_campaign=ouath-315&utm_source=gdbc&utm_medium=blog#migration).